# Determining if an item is a string or a list in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am writing a program that can have either a list or a string as an argument. How can I tell the difference between a string and a list programmatically in Erlang. Something like:

```
print(List) -> list; 
print(String) -> string.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`io_lib:printable_list` might be what you are looking for. However it doesn't handle unicode only latin-1 encodings. If you need to detect unicode strings I think you might be out of luck. The best bet is pseudo typing your lists like so: `{string, [$a, $b, $c]}`. Kind of a build your types.

Use a constructor like so `string(L) when is_list(L) -> {string, L}`. and just use that typing construct all through your app.

On the other hand you could just treat all strings as just lists and not make the distinction.

Comment: Thanks. yes, I did think of this pseudo typing, but I didn't know if it was a good way to do things in Erlang.

Comment: Another option I've seen used is to keep all strings as binaries.

Answer (score 5):

Best thing what you can do is tagging your structures as [Jeremy Wall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51233/jeremy-wall) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479713/determining-if-an-item-is-a-string-or-a-list-in-erlang/2480167#2480167). Anyway you can decide check input to your module/subsystem/application/...

```
is_string([]) -> true;
is_string([X|T]) -> is_integer(X) andalso X>=0 andalso is_string(T);
is_string(_) -> false.
```

Unfortunately it is expensive operation and you can't use it in guards.

Comment: But then a list would show up as a string in your example, is that correct?

Comment: I don't understand question. Do you mean something like `new_string(X) -> true = is_string(X), {string, X}.`? So answer is yes.

Answer (score 4):

Erlang implements different functions to test if a list is a flat list in module io_lib. Despite Jeremy Wall comment there is a function to test if a flat list contains unicode characters as well as latin1 version.

If you want to test for flat unicode lists you can use 
io_lib:char_list(Term)
http://erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#char_list-1

io_lib:char_list/1 function implementation is:

```
char_list([C|Cs]) when is_integer(C), C >= 0, C < 16#D800;
       is_integer(C), C > 16#DFFF, C < 16#FFFE;
       is_integer(C), C > 16#FFFF, C =< 16#10FFFF ->
    char_list(Cs);
char_list([]) -> true;
char_list(_) -> false.
```

One good choice for checking latin1 encoded strings is io_lib:latin1_char_list(Term)
http://erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#latin1_char_list-1

io_lib:latin1_char_list/1 function implementation is:

```
latin1_char_list([C|Cs]) when is_integer(C), C >= $\000, C =< $\377 ->
      latin1_char_list(Cs);
latin1_char_list([]) -> true;
latin1_char_list(_) -> false.
```

Check the io_lib module documentation for other similar functions.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to separate these? Strings are lists in erlang (most of the time).

Comment: The most common reason you would need to do this is a nested lists in a tree where some of the sub-lists are strings which need to be treated as a list entry not a subtree. Without tagging the list operations like flatten and tree traversal become much more difficult.

Comment: Right, in that case I second your solution with pseudo-typing as it's a way of building your own way of control flow.