# differentiate a string from a list in Erlang

Tags: erlang

In Erlang when you have a list of printable characters, its a string, but a string is also a list of items and all functions of a list can be applied onto a string. Really, the data structure *string* doesn't exist in Erlang.

Part of my code needs to be sure that something is not only a list, but it's a string. (A real string). It needs to separate lists e.g.  `[1,2,3,a,b,"josh"]` , from string e.g.  `"Muzaaya"`.

The guard expression `is_list/1` will say `true` for both strings and lists. There is no such guard as <strike>`is_string/1`</strike> and so this means I need a code snippet will make sure that my data is a string.

A string in this case is a list of only printable (alphabetical, both cases, upper and lower), and may contain numbers e.g `"Muzaaya2536 618 Joshua"`. I need a code snippet please (Erlang) that will check this for me and ensure that the variable is a string, not just a list. thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479713/determining-if-an-item-is-a-string-or-a-list-in-erlang

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have two functions in the module `io_lib` which can be helpful: [`io_lib:printable_list/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#printable_list-1) and [`io_lib:printable_unicode_list/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#printable_unicode_list-1) which test if the argument is a list of printable **latin1** or **unicode** characters respectively.

Answer (score 7):

using the isprint(3) definition of printable characters --

```
isprint(X) when X >= 32, X < 127 -> true;
isprint(_) -> false.

is_string(List) when is_list(List) -> lists:all(fun isprint/1, List);
is_string(_) -> false.
```

you won't be able to use it as a guard, though.

Comment: This works for the Latin1 character set, but it might be important to note that it will reject Unicode character codes.