# How can I detect a list [1,2,3] (not a string "example string")?

Tags: erlang

This isnt what I want [differentiate a string from a list in Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033473/differentiate-a-string-from-a-list-in-erlang)

I want to detect if a variable is a list ([1,2,3]) but when I try with is_list it is true for strings also

```
List = [2,4,6,8],
String = "example text",

%% Returns true
If is_list(List)->
   io:fwrite("is a list");
true ->
   io:fwrite("is NOT a list")
end.

%% Also returns true
If is_list(String)->
   io:fwrite("is a list");
true ->
   io:fwrite("is NOT a list")
end.
```

Comment: @legoscia the answers for the other questions wont work as they decide only if its a list or string... I want it to detect if its a list or not (a string, an integer, a tuble, etc)

Comment: The answer for the other question is OK I think. You just have to interpret in a different way. `io_lib:printable_unicode_list/1` returns true if Term is a flat list of printable Unicode characters, otherwise false. -- flat list of printable Unicode basically means a string

Comment: what I want is to detect if its a list of things ([1, "one", {1}]) or not, so if its a list it calls a specific function but if its a string, integer, map or anything other than a list ([1,2,3]) it runs another function.. like in python...

`if type(variable) == list:
    print "this is a list"
 else:
   print "this is not a list, maybe its a string, integer or something else"`

Comment: Well, then a combination of the `is_list` Guard-sequence and the `printable_unicode_list`-io-helper is the best way.

`my_function(L) when is_list(L) -> 
    case io_lib:printable_unicode_list(L) of 
        false -> true %% this is the case you want
    end
end.`

You filter out real lists with the Guard Sequence and with the io-helper you filter the cases where the list is a string.

Comment: If you don't know what a Guard-Sequence is, read this first: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards

Comment: Its not working, try it here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_erlang_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcG0wZVZpVFdOQkk

Comment: There, I've fixed the syntax-errors: https://github.com/maze-le/codingground/blob/master/New%20Project-20161021/helloworld.erl

You should definitly read about the Guard-Sequence pattern, it is only applicable in function clauses

Comment: I found a solution, can I add an answer if my account is new?